# How to correct Mismatching mapping on time series data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy, time-series

I have a small time series data :

Steps to produce data:

```
import pandas as pd 
a = [2,3,4,5,6,0,8,7,1,3,4,0,6,4,0,2,4,0,4,5,0,1,7,0,1,8,5,3,6]
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=len(a), freq="H")
ts = pd.Series(a, index=idx)
```

I want to apply a simple function to map values of the time series based on some initial and evaluated conditional parameters :

```
state = False
s = 'outside market'

def check_market_state(x):
    global state
    global s
    if state == False and x < 5 or x == 0:
        s = 'outside market'
        state = False
    if state == False and x >= 5:
        s = 'entered market'
        state = True 
    if state == True and x !=0 and x >= 5:
        s = 'inside market'
    if state == True and  x >=5:
        s = 'inside market'
    if state == True and x == 0 :
        s = 'exit market'
        state = False
    return s
```

conditions :

If threshold is 5 :

outside market if x is less than 5 and we were outside market before

entered market if x is more than equal to 5 and we were outside market before

inside market if x is less than 5  or more than 5 but not equal to zero and we were entered market or inside market before

exit market if x is equal to zero

Desired out put:
[image]

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details. In addition can you what you pass check_market_state as the variable x?

Comment: It will be great if you can provide sample input and ouput in text and conditions you want to apply.

Comment: I have edited my question with code to generate sample data and desired out put @utsav

Comment: Added details in text as well @Utsav

Comment: Please check if you r 'Steps to produce data' creating any df or series

Comment: @utsav I fixed the data generation code

Comment: @Utsav I fixed the data generation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this dataframe (`ts` and `idx` are taken from your question):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Percent_change": ts}, index=idx)
print(df)
```

```
                     Percent_change
2018-01-01 00:00:00               2
2018-01-01 01:00:00               3
2018-01-01 02:00:00               4
2018-01-01 03:00:00               5
2018-01-01 04:00:00               6
2018-01-01 05:00:00               0
2018-01-01 06:00:00               8
2018-01-01 07:00:00               7
2018-01-01 08:00:00               1
2018-01-01 09:00:00               3
2018-01-01 10:00:00               4
2018-01-01 11:00:00               0
2018-01-01 12:00:00               6
2018-01-01 13:00:00               4
2018-01-01 14:00:00               0
2018-01-01 15:00:00               2
2018-01-01 16:00:00               4
2018-01-01 17:00:00               0
2018-01-01 18:00:00               4
2018-01-01 19:00:00               5
2018-01-01 20:00:00               0
2018-01-01 21:00:00               1
2018-01-01 22:00:00               7
2018-01-01 23:00:00               0
2018-01-02 00:00:00               1
2018-01-02 01:00:00               8
2018-01-02 02:00:00               5
2018-01-02 03:00:00               3
2018-01-02 04:00:00               6
```

---

Then:

```py
def signal():
    current_state = "Outside market"

    while True:
        pct_change = yield current_state

        if (
            current_state in ("Outside market", "Market exit")
            and pct_change >= 5
        ):
            current_state = "Entered market"
        elif current_state == "Entered market" and pct_change > 0:
            current_state = "Inside market"
        elif current_state is "Market exit" and pct_change < 5:
            current_state = "Outside market"
        elif (
            current_state in ("Entered market", "Inside market")
            and pct_change == 0
        ):
            current_state = "Market exit"


s = signal()
next(s)

df["Signal"] = df["Percent_change"].apply(lambda x: s.send(x))
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(
    np.where(
        ((df["Signal"] == "Entered market") | (df["Signal"] == "Market exit")),
        df.index,
        pd.NaT,
    )
)
print(df)
```

```
                     Percent_change          Signal           Timestamp
2018-01-01 00:00:00               2  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 01:00:00               3  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 02:00:00               4  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 03:00:00               5  Entered market 2018-01-01 03:00:00
2018-01-01 04:00:00               6   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 05:00:00               0     Market exit 2018-01-01 05:00:00
2018-01-01 06:00:00               8  Entered market 2018-01-01 06:00:00
2018-01-01 07:00:00               7   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 08:00:00               1   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 09:00:00               3   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 10:00:00               4   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 11:00:00               0     Market exit 2018-01-01 11:00:00
2018-01-01 12:00:00               6  Entered market 2018-01-01 12:00:00
2018-01-01 13:00:00               4   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 14:00:00               0     Market exit 2018-01-01 14:00:00
2018-01-01 15:00:00               2  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 16:00:00               4  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 17:00:00               0  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 18:00:00               4  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 19:00:00               5  Entered market 2018-01-01 19:00:00
2018-01-01 20:00:00               0     Market exit 2018-01-01 20:00:00
2018-01-01 21:00:00               1  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-01 22:00:00               7  Entered market 2018-01-01 22:00:00
2018-01-01 23:00:00               0     Market exit 2018-01-01 23:00:00
2018-01-02 00:00:00               1  Outside market                 NaT
2018-01-02 01:00:00               8  Entered market 2018-01-02 01:00:00
2018-01-02 02:00:00               5   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-02 03:00:00               3   Inside market                 NaT
2018-01-02 04:00:00               6   Inside market                 NaT
```

Comment: THIS IS SUPERB THANKS!! It's really insightful how you have vectorized it as well @Andrej Kesely

Comment: Hi Andrej, thanks for this wonderful solution, I am currently trying to implement it on data coming from a stream like a WebSocket, when the percent change data is coming like a stream  I am unable to preserve the state, I have removed the lambda function but still struggling with how the state can be maintained continuous streaming data.